# Is tensorflow.io.gfile Module Available Without Installing the Full Tensorflow Module?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to use `tf.io.gfile` in Python without installing the full Tensorflow library?

I find it very useful because it deals with the `gs://` filesystem and can be used interchangeably with GCS URIs and local paths.

If it's not possible to use the module without installing tensorflow, is there another alternative model that gives the same level of flexibility?